# Mongoengine - id field is named None

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have noticed a weird thing happening in my application. I just can't figure out what is the systematic error that I am doing, that makes my id field to be named None.
I am using mongoengine and I defined a document such as:

```
class TestDoc(Document):
    myField = StringField()
    secondField = StringField()
```

Then, when I instantiate a Python object of type TestDoc this is what happens:

```
doc = models.TestDoc(myField="My field")
doc.save()

print doc.id
print "TESTING DOC: ", doc.__dict__
```

The result to this is:

```
>> 516d4e3cd836195263fdd45b
>> TESTING DOC:  {'_created': False, '_data': {None: ObjectId('516d4e3cd836195263fdd45b'), 'secondField': None, 'myField': 'My field'}, '_changed_fields': [], '_initialised': True}
```

I don't understand why instead of a field named "id" I end up having a weird field called None, having as value the actual id. In the DB everything seems to be fine, the documents look ok, but as soon as I retrieve a doc and wish to process it or convert it to json in order to send it over the network, this makes me problems. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_data` dictionary is an internal mongoengine dictionary and those values may not be the same values stored in the database.

Why `None` instead of `_id`? I'm not 100% sure, lost in the mists of time - but it was fixed in [#255](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/255) and will be `_id` in the next release.

Comment: Interesting...thanks! I know that the _dict is an internal mongoengine thing, but even if I try to get the properties of this document with vars(), the result is still the same. Even when I manually try to assign: doc.id = ObjectId(), the result is still a field called None. So if I need to use that object in a different function or serialize the python (mongoengine) doc to json, is there any way to get rid of that None, except for manually forcing a field called **actual_id** or smth (cause if I force a field called id, nothing happens)?

Comment: In 0.8 there will be a wrapper to handle json conversion wrapping `bson.json_util` and using `doc.to_mongo()`